# Why is my database info not showing up on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

As you can see here in my rails console I have 4 blogs but in the heroku console I have 0. I pushed my current progress to heroku. I'm using postgresql. Am I missing something obvious about getting information from my DB to heroku or do I have some problem elsewhere?

```
$ rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 28133
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
irb(main):001:0> Blog.all.count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "blogs"
=> 4


$ heroku run console
Running console on ⬢ morning-lowlands-91946... up, run.4970
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.0)
irb(main):001:0> Blog.all.count
   (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "blogs"
   (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "blogs"
=> 0
```

Comment: Had you seed your DB? It seems there is no data.

Comment: Heroku database (production) is different than your local (development) database

Answer (score 1):

> I missing something obvious.

Yes. Heroku is based on Git. Git does not track the database changes.

Answer (score 0):

As @Зелёный answered that Git does not track the changes in database. But if you want to have your development database there at Heroku, you will have to first of all create a dump file of your local data:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump
```

And then import that file to Heroku Postgres.

Here's the [official Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) on how to do the said task.